# website full width header

Tags: html, css

im doing a website but i got a problem with my header.
I want a header just like stackoverflows hearder, but my header gets spaces on the side and on the top.
this is my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.logo {
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
#header {
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    heigth: 100;

}
```

this is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Kifhood.se</title>
<link href="Untitled-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/advent-pro:n1,n3:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
          <div class="wrap">
               <div class="logo">
                    <p style="font-family: advent-pro; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; font-size: 36px; color: #FFFFFF; min-width: 0px;">Testing site</p>
               </div>             
          </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my result 
http://gyazo.com/4b0329b097fe51db377258f99d0fe2c9

Comment: Have you already removed padding & margin from the body & html elements?

Comment: I don't see any white space in your header. After all you are using `position:fixed` with (0,0).

Answer (score 3):

```
body
{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

This will solve the white around the content.

**Important**

As Cubicle Dragon pointed out the paragraph will have a margin that strikes through the header. This results in an extra white space. Replace it with another element (e.g. 'span' for text or a 'div' for block content).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#header {
background-color: #E7E7E7;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
heigth: 100;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You have unnecessary code, you could just write `body{margin: 0;}`

Comment: Just in-case in the future he wants to keep a margin at the at one of the sides then he can just change each one.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- Use a `<div>` instead of a `<p>` for your "Testing Sites" content. `<p>` has some built-in vertical margin.
- Add style on `<body>` to remove the default margin the browser may be adding

Here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t5XwZ/

Answer (score 0):

**Change your css to this:**

```
#header p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xg9tw/)

Answer (score 0):

You are very likely running into problems with the differences in default styles applied by the various browsers out there. You can add margin:0 and padding:0 to the html elements as suggested above, but there are going to be other inconsistencies that you will run into. I would strongly consider using a css reset or normalize to fix most of these inconsistencies.

I use eric meyer's version 2, but there are many to choose from: http://www.cssreset.com/